# Switching between animations in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been working on this all day yesterday. Attempting a few different methods. But I can't seem to figure it out. I am new with Unity but until this point everything was going smoothly. I am trying to get my character to switch between the 'walking' and 'idle' animations i've made.

```
if(Input.GetKey ("left")){
transform.position.x = transform.position.x - 0.1;
animator.Play("walking");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to make it play the idol animation when none of the movement keys are pressed.

```
if(Input.GetKey ("left")){
transform.position.x = transform.position.x - 0.1;
animation.Play("walking");
}

if(!Input.GetKey ("left")){
animation.Play("idle");
}
```

Also, animator should instead be animation.

Comment: Well I keep getting this error "unknown identifier: 'animator'"

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to change the part of the code that said animator to animation.

Comment: Oh! Well let me try that and I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok.. Well now this isn't making any sense to me. It says 'There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Character" game object'.

Comment: In the inspector of the gameobject, if there is no Animation component  you need to add one in order for animations to work. And make sure that both your "walking" and "idle" animations are added to it.

Comment: I do. It has controller : Character. Avatar : none.

Comment: That is the Animator component, it also needs an Animation component.

Comment: Wow that gets confusing.. I can't find it in the 'add component' could you tell me where to find it?

Comment: It is categorized under miscellaneous, in the add component.

Comment: and now this 'The AnimationClip 'walking' used by the Animation component 'Character' must be marked as Legacy.
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()' came up 5 out of the 6 errors.

Comment: Assuming the model is imported, click on it in the project view. And under the rig tab in the inspector, change animation type to legacy.

Comment: Ok I'm not seeing a rig tab. Does it help to know this is a 2D sprite?

Comment: Oh, that changes things. Check this out: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/577801/animation-must-be-marked-as-legacy.html

Comment: Ok that worked great. I do have one last issue here. I saw it earlier but I didn't think it would be a problem. I have several animations to add to the character. Idle, Walking Left, Walking Right but it's only letting me add one to it so I am now back to that error ' The animation state Idle could not be played because it couldn't be found!
Please attach an animation clip with the name 'Idle' or call this function only for existing animations.
UnityEngine.Animation:Play(String)
controller:Update() (at Assets/myAssets/Scripts/controller.js:13) '

Comment: It could perhaps be that you need to increase the size of the dropdown called animations, in the Animation component. Set it to what ever size you need for all of your animations to fit, then drag the animations into the slots. The animation that is in the first slot called "Animation", is the one that will be played automatically from the start, so I would recommend making that one the "idle" animation.